# I want search that there is a $ y \in Q_{8} $ such that $ Q_{8} = \langle y \rangle Z(Q_{8}) $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want search that there is a $ y \in Q_{8} $ such that $ Q_{8} = \langle y \rangle Z(Q_{8}) $. We know $ Z(Q_{8}) $ isomorphic to cyclic group $ C_{2} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such element $y$. This is because the quotient group $Q_8/Z(Q_8)$ is isomorphic to the Klein group $V_4$, which is not cyclic.  Alternatively, you could hand check all options since the group $Q_8$ is so small.

Answer (score 1):

Darko's answer is probably the best way to think about things here. However, it's not too hard to see (or directly compute) that $Z(Q_{8}) = \langle - 1 \rangle = \{-1, 1\} \subset Q_{8}$. Note that the cyclic group generated by any nonidentity element $y$ of $Q_{8}$ contains $\pm 1$, so in fact, $\langle y \rangle Z(Q_{8}) = \langle y \rangle$ for every $y \neq e \in Q_{8}$. Hence, since every element of $Q_{8}$ has order at most $4$ (or alternatively, because $Q_{8}$ is not cyclic), we can't have $\langle y \rangle Z(Q_{8}) = Q_{8}$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since $Z(Q_8) \lhd Q_8$, if there was such a $y$, then $Q_8$ would be a semi-direct product of $\langle y\rangle$ and $Z(Q_8)$, but $Q_8$ cannot be realized as *any* semi-direct product.